Explaining the nature of complex roots of a quartic
I am attempting to come up with an explanation for the possible types of roots of a quartic equation of the form,

$az^4+bz^3+cz^2+dz+e=0,\quad z\in\mathbb{C}, a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R}$

It needs to be an explanation on the level of second-year A-Level students.
I initially thought of saying that the equation can be factorised into two quadratics so,

$(z^2+fz+g)(hz^2+jz+k)=0,\quad z\in\mathbb{C}, f,g,h,j,k\in\mathbb{R}$

Then stating that since each quadratic can have either two real roots or a complex conjugate pair, the possibilities for the quartic are:

Four real roots
One complex conjugate pair and two real
Two complex conjugate pairs.

The problem here is that I haven't justified that the quartic can be factorised into two quadratics. I thought about explaining it by saying that if the quartic has four roots, $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta$, then it must factorise as,

$(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)(z-\gamma)(z-\delta)=0,\quad z,\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta \in \mathbb{C}$

so the brackets could pair up and form two quadratics.
I then thought that I could justify the cases just by looking at the factorisation into four brackets, as above. I thought that in order to give real coefficients when expanded, the cases in the bulleted list above must apply.
The problem there is that I haven't really justified that this is the case. I mean that I haven't justified that you couldn't have, for example, four imaginary roots that are not conjugate pairs that would expand to give real coefficients.
Basically, I've ended up confusing myself more than when I started. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Are you allowed to use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra?

Suppose that $z=a+bi$ with $b\neq 0$, and $p(z)=0$. What can you say about $p(\overline{z})$?

I think you can go step by step (like an induction). First show that quadratic equation must have $2$ real roots or $2$ complex conjugate roots (This is easy). Next to show that a cubic equation must either have $1$ real root + $2$ complex conjugate or $3$ real roots. You can use the idea of Intermediate value theorem (without stating the exact theorem, but the idea behind is easy to understand by graphical illustration), this shows that a cubic equation must have at least $1$ real root. By factor theorem, this can reduce into a product of linear factor and quadratic factor. (TBC)

Now by the quadratic discussion, we can show that cubic equation can only have those two cases. With this idea, we can generalize to quartic equation. However, this approach relies on the use of Fundamental theorem of algebra and also factor theorem of polynomials.

@AngaeMT The extension to quartic is not so easy since it is not guaranteed to have a real root to let us simplify down to a cubic.

@AngaeMT Thanks for the suggestions. I have justified the cases for a cubic as you suggested, by stating that there must be one real root (just from the shape of the cubic) and that therefore it factorises into a linear and a quadratic, then adding in the cases for the roots of a quadratic. It's the jump to quartic that is confusing me.

Yah but you can still classify the cases, if you have 0 real roots, then we are done. If you have 1 real roots, then it can reduce to $(x-a)(x^3+bx^2+cx+d)=0$, now by cubic discussion you can show that it must be a 2 real roots (or 4 real roots) cases. This can eliminate 1 real root and 3 real roots case. Moreover, the conjugate pairs followed from quadratic discussion. (But this seems cannot explain why 4 nonreal roots must be 2 pairs of conjugate lol)

A little more on Max Chein's comment: Imagine the complex plane, with the roots lit up in one color (I pick green.) and the coefficients of the polynomial lit up in another color (I pick blue.).  If we flip the plane over around the real axis (that is take $z \mapsto \mathrm{i}z$) the coefficients (blue lights) don't move, so the roots (green lights) collectively have to land on themselves -- so each root either is on the real axis (lands on itself) or is half of a conjugate pair (the pair swap places).

@AngaeMT Yes, that's a good idea. If there is one real root then we can do what you suggest with the cubic and justify the cases. You're right, it's the two conjugate pairs case that's causing me trouble.

BTW: I may not have been clear: we apply $z \mapsto \mathrm{i}z$ to all the numbers, not to the variable $x$.  If we "just" do this to the roots, the various symmetric polynomials expressing the coeffcients in terms of the roots must all have the same values, since the coefficients didn't move under this change of numbers.  In the other direction, since the coefficients didn't move, the roots have to land on the roots.

@AngaeMT I don't quite understand what you mean by 'if you have 0 real roots, then we are done.' how would you justify this?

Summarizing the comments into an answer, based on the assumption that your A level students know that a polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ complex roots (counting multiplicities) and that complex conjugation preserves arithmetic operations on complex numbers and fixes the real axis.
It follows that if $\alpha$ is a root then so is $\bar \alpha$. Thus the nonreal roots occur in conjugate pairs. There may be two such pairs, or one, or none, corresponding to $0$, $2$ or $4$ real roots. No need to think about factoring into two quadratics, or a linear and a cubic.

Thank you for this. I think I will start by demonstrating the distributive and commutative properties of the complex conjugate, then using those to state that if a complex numbers is a root of a polynomial, so is its conjugate, and therefore complex roots must come in conjugate pairs. Then I can just list the cases for each order polynomial. I think that's all within the grasp of A Level students. I don't need to go into factorisation.

You're welcome. It's not distributive and commutative properties you want, it's that conjugation preserves addition and multiplication. $\overline{\alpha + \beta} = \bar\alpha + \bar\beta$ and $\overline{\alpha \beta} = \bar\alpha \bar\beta$ . The technical term is that it's a ring homomorphism.
